# Does IIS have a setting for maximum number of logins under forms authentication?

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7.5

I have not been able to find any information on setting the maximum invalid login attempts in forms authentication for IIS.  Is there a maximum you can set?

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not even know what is forms authentication, as that's an ASP.NET layer thing. So there is no such a setting.

Comment: I'm seeing Forms Authentication as an IIS security role.

Comment: @user2480149 it appears to be but in fact not. A mess when Microsoft designed it and shipped it that way.